# Windows 7 doesn't loads after Solaris attempted install

Tags: windows, solaris, partitioning, ntfs

I got two hard disks, one of 40gb and another one with 1tb.

The 40gb has windows 7 installed on it, taking all the space of this hdd, and in the 1tb disk i got few logic and extended partitions; in this order:

1) Windows 8 2) Microsoft Server 2012 3) Empty storage partition 4) Ubuntu 12.04 precise pangolin

And some empty extended partitions with non partitioned space as well.

However, i put the Solaris 11 Automated install on my DVD, restarted my pc, and booted from this Solaris DVD, then it started to read parameters of my pc, and suddendly started to download the packages. No partitions screen, no way to know what was actually going on (i thought it will show me or AT LEAST select en empty partition or empty space on my second hdd (1tb one)).

Anyway, it started to download packages, and for any reason i stopped the process (it was just starting to download) and after that rebooted my machine.

As i told before, the first 40gb hdd had windows7 fully installed on it, then i cannot access my windows 7 installation anymore, i can just access the ubuntu one, and what's more amusing i can'tr even see this hdd from system devices in Ubuntu, as i saw on windows 8 rescue system, seems like it's gpt partition right now.

I don't know or i don't think it erased and formatted everything in such a short time.

This automated install just looks for the first disk and erase everything? Being used or not? I don't think so...

I need urgent help with this.

I think that maaaybe it just overran the MBR or something like that.

Already tried with repair installation from windows 7 dvd but no luck.

Could somebody shed some light upon this?

I hope i've explained myself.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When i started reading your question, i was thinking about an overwritten MRB.

However, if the partition table changed from MBR to GPT, all partitions on the harddrive have been killed.

Comment: Well it is maybe the case, i just test it on GPARTED and it says theres is an unknown filesystem on it, but when i check the HDD (on GPARTED as well) it says there is indeed an NTFS filesystem, idk, but it's maybe gone